# Problem of disk space when querying with entity framework core

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

Hi I'm executing this query:

```
Account account = await _ctx.Account.Include(a => a.AccountCloseFriends)
                            .ThenInclude(acf => acf.CloseFriends)
                            .Include(a => a.AccountCloseFriends.Plans)
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.AccountId == model.AccountIdInfluencer);
```

It was working well, but after many times  I executed this query, the error below appeared:

[image]

I didn't find the folder described on the error and I have disk space free.

What can I do ?

Comment: Your disk is full, free some space.

Comment: It's not full I've already checked

Comment: Would you not check the account ID first, then get all additional data? save trying to send over half the database

Comment: Maybe you checked, but windows thinks otherwise

Comment: @BugFinder I did not understand.

Comment: @bradbury9 How can I be sure?

Comment: @makeItEasier you include a whole load of stuff and then say "if account id = whatever" .. if you did that first you would reduce all the data being collected